# PHP ActiveRecord adding underscore

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm trying to use PHP ActiveRecord in Codeigniter.

I have a model like this:

```
<?php class tblAdmins extends ActiveRecord\Model {}
```

In my controller I have this:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->spark('php-activerecord/0.0.2');
    }

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -  
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
         $name = tblAdmins::find_by_username('myname');
        /*$this->load->view('welcome_message');*/
    }
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

When open the page in CodeIgniter I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with
>   message '42S02, 1146, Table 'CampusRecMobile.tbl_admins' doesn't
>   exist' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php:313
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\adapters\MysqlAdapter.php(25):
>   ActiveRecord\Connection->query('SHOW COLUMNS FR...') #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php(254):
>   ActiveRecord\MysqlAdapter->query_column_info('`tbl_admins`') #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(370):
>   ActiveRecord\Connection->columns('`tbl_admins`') #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Cache.php(67):
>   ActiveRecord{closure}() #4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(370):
>   ActiveRecord\Cache::get('get_meta_data-`.. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php
>   on line 313

Instead of looking for CampusRecMobile.*tblAdmins* it's looking for CampusRecMobile.tbl_admins (which is not a table). How can I get rid of this underscore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell the AR Model which table to use

```
static $table_name = "tblAdmins";
```